# When get datetime value from session getting error The json value could not be converted to system.datetime

Tags: asp.net-core, session

I am running one Asp.net core application where one of the method i set the datetime value to one session like below:

```html
 if (_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.Get(SessionKeys.UserSpentTime) == null)
                _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.Set(SessionKeys.UserSpentTime, DateTime.Now);
```

Then in another method i first verify this session contains the value or not if contains then get the same value from the session like below:

```html
if (_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.Get(SessionKeys.UserSpentTime) != null)
            {
                DateTime getInitialSpentTimeByUser = Convert.ToDateTime(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.Get<DateTime>(SessionKeys.UserSpentTime));
                
            }
```

But getting error while getting from the session and error is: The Json value could not converted to System.Datetime

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SetString to replace Set,here is a demo worked:

```
        public IActionResult SetSession()
        {
            _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString("_Time", DateTime.Now.ToString());
            return Ok();
        }
        public IActionResult GetSession()
        {
            var time= Convert.ToDateTime(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("_Time"));
            return Ok(time);
        }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: As your suggested solution working for me. One last question how could i make this session null which contains string?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any issue now. Thank you.